# Given the anonymous function below, what does the "<fun:clo@1>" mean in the function signature?

Tags: function, f#, signature

In this F# anonymous function signature, what does the "fun:clo@1" mean ?

```
(fun x-> x+2);;
val it : x:int -> int = <fun:clo@1>
```

I understand what the anonymous function is doing, and i understand the rest of the signature, and I've looked around for an answer, but have yet to figure out what the "" means ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part is essentially an auto-generated name for the function.

The `fun` part is because it is a function.

The `clo` will on some cases be replaced by a version of the containing function if the lambda is inside another function.

The `@1` is because it is the first lambda in the function.

All of this is really an implementation detail though and could probably change between releases